# Plugging an electrical instrument into computer

Tags: electric-guitar

I have an electric baritone ukulele, that I would like to record music directly into my os Windows 7 computer. Is this possible?

Comment: Does the ukulele have an onboard preamplifier?

Comment: @topomorto "Shit I never thought I'd hear" for $400, Alex :-)

Answer (score 4):

We have a lot of questions on this topic, but I have yet to find an exact duplicate.

The answer is yes - all you need is an audio interface. There are many on the market, so just look for one with a standard electric guitar input, and USB connection to the PC.

ASIO drivers are available for Windows 7 - use these for low latency.

As far as audio software goes, any audio recorder will work for basic recording. Audacity gives you some excellent editing functionality. And a full on Digital Audio Workstation such as Cubase, Sonar or ProTools gives you a full functionality suite.